# Same function Buttons but used them separately Vue & Vuetify

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/iamamagicman/pen/QrOjOe)

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    Frequired: true,
    Lrequired: false
  }),
  methods: {
    handleChanges () {
      this.Frequired = !this.Frequired;  
      this.Lrequired = !this.Lrequired;  
    }
  }
})
```

How do I use the same function botton /checkout but use them separately?

In the example above, I would love to do a check for Required **First Name** Field and do a check on **Last Name** Field, now the function links to both checkbox, would love to know a clean way to click them separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may remove `handleChanges` and use something like this

```
@click="Frequired = !Frequired"
```

and

```
@click="Lrequired= !Lrequired"
```

demo: https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/ZoabNB?editors=1000

Comment: Thanks man, its a quick and clean way to manipulate the function.

Answer (score 0):

** as @Jacob Goh said, or if you need more logic then

You can pass a param instead of doing

```
<v-checkbox label="Required" @click="handleChanges"></v-checkbox>
```

you can do

```
<v-checkbox label="Required" @click="handleChanges('f')"></v-checkbox>
```

and check for it in your method

```
  methods: {
    handleChanges (param) {
      if(param==='f'){ 
          this.Frequired = !this.Frequired;  
          // do more stuff
      }else {
          this.Lrequired = !this.Lrequired; 
          // do more stuff
      }
    }
  }
```